# Compiling with Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit

I have two .class files that I'm supposed to black box test.  These are in a package `one.two.three`.  My tests are also in the same package.  There is a third .class file in the same package whose purpose is to hold an enum variable for the `Orders` class I'm supposed to test.  In eclipse, I'm able to get the junit tests for `Orders` to work by importing the enum directly e.g.

```
import one.two.three.Orders.ShippingMethod;
```

If I try to do this using Ant or via the command line, I get the error "package one.two.three.Orders does not exist".  If I change the import statement to

```
import one.two.three.*;
```

Ant, Eclipse, and the terminal cannot find any of the classes I have.  I need to compile and run the test cases with Ant.  The classes are in `bin/one/two/three` Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `Orders`, as it is the class, and assuming that `ShippingMethod` is an enum within that class, the correct way to reference its type is `Orders.ShippingMethod`.

Attempting to import a class's internal types sometimes works oddly in Eclipse.  This is likely due to Eclipse not using the `javac` compiler packaged in your jdk, while Ant does (it has to, because Ant doesn't ship an embedded compiler).

```
 import one.two.three.Orders;


 public class Whatever {

    private Orders.ShippingMethod shipMethod;

 }
```

This should work in everything, as it's the right way to do it.

```
 import one.two.three.Orders.ShippingMethod;
```

could easily confuse *most* compilers as there is not a

```
 one/two/three/Orders/ShippingMethod.class
```

file, which means the class loader won't find it at runtime.

I'll bet it's a bug in the Eclipse embedded compiler, as I've seen quite a few.  On the bright side, the Eclipse embedded compiler exists to provide faster, tighter integration between code editing and Eclipse.  On the dark side, that means that sometimes the Eclipse compiler and the `javac` compiler differ.  When in doubt, the `javac` compiler is probably correct.

Comment: thx edwin, when I do import one.two.three.Orders, it says it  cannot find the symbol Orders in package one.two.three

Comment: Is Orders a _public_ class?  If not, you might be running into the public, private, protected, <implied package> barriers...

Comment: It's an assignment for a testing class, the prof only gave us the .class files.  The instructions he gave us were that the .class files and the testing files had to be in the same package to use

Comment: @Steve Try running javap on the class file.  It takes the same general parameters as the java command.  It should print out enough detail about the class to determine what's really in it.  Hopefully between that and this post, you will have what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Edwin, I always assumed eclipse was the god of java and was foolproof.  After ditching it and just running through the command line, I was able to fine tune a couple errors and get it to work.  Thanks again

Comment: @Steve You're welcome, it is so good to hear about your success.  Eclipse is pretty good, but that built-in compiler can bite you sometimes.  If you have the time, look at Netbeans.  It's done a bit differently, and recently I've had much better luck with it over Eclipse; hopefully you will too.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the classpath.

I don't know exactly on Eclipse (I use NetBeans), but I click on `Libraries -> add JAR/Folder`.

For command line, you need to specify class path

`java -cp path/to/my/files (...)`